# DBPROCESS is dead or inactive when connecting to MSSQL Server in Codeignitor

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, ftp, sqlsrv

I am having a web page which list number of files in AZURE Storage using FTP connection using PHP/Codeignitor. This page also connect to the MSSQL Server also. Some times we are getting 500 error and when checked the Apache log we found that it is a database error "**DBPROCESS is dead or inactive**".

If we refresh the it will load the pages correctly. If anyone having idea about this error, please help. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Typically that error indicates the connection was terminated in some fashion - perhaps the network connection was severed or the db connection will killed. No way to debug it after the fact without more information. Might be something useful in the server logs - after your network and dba teams for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlalchemy, a solution can be to use `pool_pre_ping=True` while creating the SQL engine:

```
engine = create_engine(SQL_URL, pool_pre_ping=True)
```

For me, the error occurred after creating the SQL connection variable globally, which became dead after not using for a long time.

So, instead of creating the SQL connection variable globally, I created it for each function call.

More details [here](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/402#issuecomment-1356793443)