AWS Fargate API keeps dropping out
I have a Fargate cluster setup to handle my API. It keeps dropping out, and I'm not sure what is causing it. When I say dropping out, I mean that when I first deploy the image, it works fine. But after maybe an hour of no use, it stops working entirely.
The API is hidden behind API gateway. It runs on a docker image pushed to AWS ECR. I just don't understand how it can work for a while and then just drop out completely. I haven't done any particular diagnostic tests on exactly when it drops out - whether it's a specific timeframe or after a certain period of inactivity. It also seems to fix itself after a while, then have the same issues. There is no health checks on the container.
I'm not sure of other details which would be useful to anyone looking at this - ask for anything you need to diagnose this issue and I'll update this question with the relevant details. Perhaps I'm just using the wrong tool for this purpose, perhaps I need a standard EC2 instance for this? I just like the scalability that Fargate provides.
EDIT - I found this error in CloudWatch after someone suggested taking a look there:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymssql.exceptions.OperationalError) (20047, b'DB-Lib error message 20047, severity 9:\nDBPROCESS is dead or not enabled\n')

I'm not sure what it means though.

I assume this is an ECS task running on Fargate? Have you checked the conatiner logs in CloudWatch Logs to see if there are any errors there? Is it behind a load balancer? If it is, does the load balancer say it is healthy? Your question is very short on concrete details so it's not going to be possible for anyone to help unless you edit the question to add some specifics.

I'm quite new to AWS, sorry for the lack of information. I've just checked the CloudWatch logs and this is an error that was most recent from this morning, it seems like it might be related?
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymssql.exceptions.OperationalError) (20047, b'DB-Lib error message 20047, severity 9:\nDBPROCESS is dead or not enabled\n')

One thought I had was that it uses waitress to serve the app on Fargate. I was wondering if it was due to a DB connection being kept open in SQLAlchemy/pmssql and the DB closing the connection after a period of it not being used. Then silently erroring, causing requests made to the API to time out (which is what is currently happening).
Maybe I should look at manually closing DB connections? I assumed Python would handle it but maybe that isn't the case.

Yes, that looks like it might be some sort of DB connection timeout issue, but I'm not sure. I'm not familiar with waitress. I would look into the way you are creating the DB connections, and any connection pool settings. This answer looks promising https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71112727/dbprocess-is-dead-or-inactive-when-connecting-to-mssql-server-in-codeignitor

I am testing the pool_pre_ping option now, and will update if it fixes the issue. Thanks for all your help in diagnosing this issue!
